# Is there a dynamic way of including class name as property in JSON return value from web service

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am writing a web service (c#, minimal api) for a front end application in Typescript. For type checking I want to include a type property in my JSON returned from the web service.

Example:

Following result expected in the front end

```
{
   "name": "Jason",
   "type": "User"
}
```

The user class in the backend will look like this

```
public class User {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //I do not want to have this property in every class
    public string Type { 
        get {
            return "User";
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I have to add the property Type to every single class in the web service. Is there a way to tell the JSON serializer to do it for me?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    //do something here to achieve a "type" property?
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## dotnet 7+ update

Now its possible to do polymorphic serialization, here is a short example code:

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(opt =>
        {
            opt.SerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
        });

        var app = builder.Build();
        app.MapGet("/", () => new List<A> { new A(), new B(), new C() });
        app.Run();
    }

    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(B), nameof(B))]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(C), nameof(C))]
    private class A
    {
        public string _a { get; set; } = "this is a";
    }

    private class B : A
    {
        public string _b { get; set; } = "this is b";
    }

    private class C : A
    {
        public string _c { get; set; } = "this is c";
    }
}
```

Typical response on a "/" path:

```
[
  {
    "_a": "this is a"
  },
  {
    "$type": "B",
    "_b": "this is b",
    "_a": "this is a"
  },
  {
    "$type": "C",
    "_c": "this is c",
    "_a": "this is a"
  }
]
```

Microsoft [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0) on it.

Basically there are 2 attributes:

- *JsonDerivedTypeAttribute* - being placed on a base class and specified which types to handle. Also, you have to provide here a value for type discrimination. I used *nameof* operator in the example.
- *JsonPolymorphicAttribute* - allows to change name of the *type discriminator* property. Default is *$type*.

Example of setting *JsonPolymorphicAttribute* on a base class:

```cs
    [JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "meowza")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(B), nameof(B))]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(C), nameof(C))]
    private class A
    {
        public string _a { get; set; } = "this is a";
    }
```

results in following output:

```
[
  {
    "_a": "this is a"
  },
  {
    "meowza": "B",
    "_b": "this is b",
    "_a": "this is a"
  },
  {
    "meowza": "C",
    "_c": "this is c",
    "_a": "this is a"
  }
]
```

---

Minimal api uses built in *System.Text.Json* json serializer implementation <s>which doesn't support polymorphic de\serialization of object.</s>

<s>To achieve that you want (not providing type explicitly) you'll have to use 3rd party json serializer such as [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)</s>

Minimal api is highly opinionated by design and enabling Json.Net there is cumbersome.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850917/how-to-configure-newtonsoftjson-with-minimalapi-in-net-6-0) answer for further info.