# Is it possible to restrict JsonConverter registered on a property to only run during model binding?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, system.text.json

I have a Web API application that serves an endpoint: `POST: /api/Partition` and accepts a JSON object with the following structure:

```
{
    // myProperty is a string array
    myProperty: [ "a", "b" ]
}
```

However, the corresponding WebAPI controller action accepts a class with the following structure:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<MyClass> Post(MyClass postObject)
{
    ...
}

public class MyClass 
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set;}
}
```

I needed to convert MyProperty from a `string[]` to a `string`. Therefore I wrote this custom JsonConverter and registered it to `MyProperty`.

```
public class StringToStringArrayJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            reader.Read();
            while (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
            {
                list.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(ref reader, options)!);
                reader.Read();
            }
            return string.Join(",", list);
        }
        return reader.GetString();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

// Register JsonConverter on MyProperty
public class MyClass 
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringToStringArrayJsonConverter))]
    public string MyProperty { get; set;}
}
```

However, I would like this JsonConverter to only take effect during model binding before the controller action runs. Right now, it is also used whenever I use
`JsonSerializer.Serialize()` and `JsonSerializer.Deserialize()`, and I don't want that to happen. How do I override the registered JsonConverter whenever I want to use the JsonSerializer?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question.  Are you asking how to make a `JsonConverter<T>` use custom deserialization but fall back to default serialization?  If so see [How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65430420/3744182).  Or are you asking how to make asp.net-core generate different contracts for model binding and formatting, so that the `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringToStringArrayJsonConverter))]` attribute is completely ignored for the formatting contract?

Comment: @dbc Your second point, basically. I want my custom JsonConverter to only be used for model binding and formatting, not for serialization.

Comment: Then why do you only want `StringToStringArrayJsonConverter` to take effect during deserialization?  As currently written your `Write()` method will do the same thing as default serialization, won't it?

Comment: And why does your Endpoint takes that class instead of something more like the thing you actually want to transfer as Json? I do  not understand the problem for what you need a JsonConverter in the first place.

Comment: This kinda feels like you are just trying to bend the `MyClass` object to do too many things. Just have different classes and all this complication goes away.

Comment: @Ralf `MyClass` is basically the class that is used as the response for a get request, and also as the payload for a post request. Therefore it needs to be converted from `string[]` to `string` and vice versa, only during model binding. Why I chose to structure MyClass differently from the expected payload is an entirely different reason, and restructuring MyClass will eventually lead to more complexity in other areas of my application (e.g. way too many mapping functions).

Comment: @Sharon you should prevent using the same class for request and response then. The problem with many mappings can't be that bad that what you try to achive here will be any better.

Comment: @dbc I don't want the jsonConverter to be used for serialization or deserialization. I only want it to be used during model binding.

Comment: Just to confirm, you do mean `[FromBody]` model binding from a JSON body, right?  Because `[FromBody]` JSON model binding is done via deserialization.

Comment: @dbc yes, exactly.

Comment: Then you probably need to look into a custom model binder.  See e.g. [How do I add a custom ModelBinder to a custom type inside a C# class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76562986).  A custom model binder should be able to apply the JSON converter.

Answer (score 0):

it is better for you to not override the jsonconverter class because of some standard in class configuration.

the problem you are encountered is that you should be on a same rule with controller output data, so it is better for your function to use getter-setter for your MyClass class.

in setter you can make the desired value and in getter you can return it.