# .NET Minimal API BadRequest response does not return the body

Tags: .net, minimal-apis

```
app.MapPost($"{root}/v1/AuthenticateUser"
    , async Task<Results<Ok<GetTokenForResponse>, BadRequest<ErrorModel>>> 
    (HttpContext httpContext, IMediator mediator, AuthenticateBody body) =>
{
    var response = await mediator.Send(new AuthenticateUserHandler.Request(httpContext, body.UserName, body.Password));
    if (response.IsSuccessful)
        return TypedResults.Ok(response.Result);
    return TypedResults.BadRequest(response.Error);
})
.WithTags(root);
```

I am currently running on .NET 7
I am not finding any clues as to why the `BadRequest` method will NOT return the body
[Results.BadRequest Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.badrequest?view=aspnetcore-7.0#BadRequest(Object)) on MS Docs

It appears that this should be returning whatever object is defined at the get go.  But, for some reason, it is not.  ***Am I missing something?***

```
public record BaseResponse<T>
{
    public HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccessful => Error is null && Result is not null;
    public ErrorModel? Error { get; set; }
    public T? Result { get; set; }
}
```

In this example, `T` is of a class called `GetTokenFor_Response`.  The `Ok` path returns a valid body.  The `BadRequest` does not.

NOTE:  Adding screenshot of Response object coming back from Mediatr:
[image]

NOTE 2:
Issue opened on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/50964).

NOTE 3:
Changed the Error object like this and it now works.  The error was not in the BadRequest method per se.  It was a record that did not have public getters?  I think?
[image]

Comment: hi, are you sure the response.Error property is actually populated before sending it?

Comment: Absolutely - 100%.  Added screen shot to OP.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: No logs are yet turned on.  Greenfield about 4 hours old - working on a single thread of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the record definition was adequate while inside my code, yet when sent via the `BadRequest` method something got lost in the translation.  I am guessing, emphasize guessing, that public getter/setters not being explicitly defined was the ultimate culprit.

The following changes in the error object definition fixed this issue:
[image]

See answer from @Guru-Stron.  Fills in several blanks for me.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal APIs use `System.Text.Json` and `JsonPropertyAttribute` (highly likely) is from Newtonsoft's Json.NET.

There are workarounds to use Newtonsoft's Json.NET with Minimal APIs (for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867815/2501279)) but in general it not worth the hustle.

As for `System.Text.Json` - by default it does not serialize fields, to enable fields serialization you need to either use `JsonIncludeAttribute` or set `JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields` to `true` (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0#include-fields)). For example:

```
// this namespace is for Minimal APIs
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(opts =>
    opts.SerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true);
```

Or via special extension method:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(opts => opts.SerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true);
```

P.S.

AFAIK you don't need to specify [attribute target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/#attribute-targets) (i.e. `field:` ) in your case.